# Multi-slot transclusion in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a component with multi-slot transclusion in Angular 6, following [this blog post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content) (which is for Angular 2).

I created a component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-criteria',
  template: `
    <div class="adoption-grid-column adopter">
      <div class="adoption-grid-icon ">
        <ng-content select="level-icon"></ng-content>
      </div>

      <div class="adoption-grid-body">
        <ng-content select="level-description"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class CriteriaComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and then I am trying to use it like this

```
<app-criteria>
    <level-icon>
        foo
    </level-icon>
    <level-description>
        bar
    </level-description>
</app-criteria>
```

But it throws a compile error:

`ERROR in : 'level-icon' is not a known element`

What am I missing here?

I realize I could create sub-components here, but I'm looking for a solution where I can pass blocks of html into slots in my component (such as bulleted lists, images, etc.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest solution (the one I prefer) is to create subcomponents with `ng-content` as you mentioned. If you don't want to create such components, there are two things you can do.

1. `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`

You can tell angular to skip over the components it does not recognize by adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to `schema` array of your feature module.

E.g.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...]
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class CustomModule { }
```

With this way, angular will not complain about `level-icon` or `level-description` and transclusion will work just fine. However, setting this option may hide other problems you could have. For example, you can make a typo when using a component and since you told angular you would have `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS`, it will not give you an error. You end up debugging your code and wondering why the brand new component you just developed is not working.

2. Selecting classes or attributes other than elements.

When you write `<ng-content select="level-icon"></ng-content>` angular will actually look for html elements called `level-icon`. You can have it search for classes, attributes etc. So what you can do is to change this

`<ng-content select="level-icon"></ng-content>`

to

`<ng-content select="[level-icon]"></ng-content>`

or

`<ng-content select=".level-icon"></ng-content>`

And use your component as follows

```
<app-criteria>
    <div level-icon>
        foo
    </div>
</app-criteria>
```

or

```
<app-criteria>
    <div class="level-icon">
        foo
    </div>
</app-criteria>
```

With this way, you can `select` for `ul`, or `img`. Basically anything you want.

If you still want to use `<level-icon>` as element, you either have to create a subcomponent or use `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`.

Comment: Sweet.  I wound up using the ` <div level-icon>` format.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ngProjectAs`

```
<div ngProjectAs="level-icon">...</div>
<div ngProjectAs="level-description">...</div>
```

In this case you don't need to disable tag validation